# Usage of postgres jsonb

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to work better with json in postgres.

I have a file that stores information about many tables (structure and values). File is periodically updated, this may mean changes in data as well as in table structures. It turns out some kind of dynamic tables.

As a result, I have json table structure (key is column, value is field type (string or number only)) and list of json records for each table.

Something like this (actualy structure does not matter):

```
{
    'table_name': 'table1',
    'columns': {
        'id': 'int',
        'data1': 'string',
        'data2': 'string'
    },
    'values': [
        [1, 'aaa', 'bbb'],
        [2, 'ccc', 'ddd']
    ]
}
```

At first I wanted to make a real table for each table in file, do truncate when updating the data and drop table if table structure changes. Second option I'm testing now is a single table with json data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.data_tables
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    table_name character varying(50),
    row_data jsonb,
    CONSTRAINT data_tables_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

And now there is the question of how to properly work with json:

1. directly query row_data like `row_data->>'id' = 1` with hash index for 'id' key
2. use `jsonb_populate_record` with custom types for each table (yes, I need to recreate them each time table structure will change)
3. probably some other way to work with it?

First option is the easiest and fast because of indexes, but there is no data type control and you have to put it in every query.

Second option is more difficult to implement, but easier to use in queries. I can even create views for each table with `jsonb_populate_record`. But as far as I see - indexes won't work with json function?

Perhaps there is a better way? Or is recreating tables not such a bad option?

Comment: From the database perspective, I can only recommend dynamically created tables without JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `JSON` string is not the correct format. I wrote the corrected sample JSON string:

```
{
    "table_name": "table1",
    "columns": {
        "id": "integer",
        "data1": "text",
        "data2": "text"
    },
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "data1": "aaa",
            "data2": "bbb"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "data1": "ccc",
            "data2": "ddd"
        }
    ]
}
```

I wrote a sample function for you, but only for `creating table` from JSON. You can write SQL code for inserting process too, it's easy, not difficult.

Sample Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_create_table()
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    rec record;
begin

    FOR rec IN
            select 
                t1.table_name,  
                string_agg(t2.pkey || ' ' || t2.pval || ' NULL', ', ') as sql_columns 
            from data_tables t1
            cross join jsonb_each_text(t1.row_data->'columns') t2(pkey, pval) 
            group by t1.table_name 
    loop
        execute 'create table ' ||  rec.table_name || ' (' || rec.sql_columns || ')';
    END loop;
   
    return true; 

END;
$function$;
```

Comment: Thanks for function example. But my main question was if delete/create multiple tables is a good solution in db layer.